# 4D Set Username & Password for PHP Connection with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, 4d-database

I'm setting up a PHP script that connects to the 4D Database on my local system.

However, I keep getting:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'tester'' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/4d/index.php:8 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/4d/index.php(8): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'XXXX', 'XXXX') #1 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/4d/index.php on line 8
```

I don't know HOW and WHERE to set the username & password for permissions for PHP to connect to the database :/

Any help is appreciated.

Simple code:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tester', "tester", "");

try {
echo "OK";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
die("Error 4D : " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For connect 4D, you must to use like :

```
$db = new PDO('4d:host=localhost;charset=UTF-8', "tester", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Connections to 4D Server from `PDO_4D` must either utilize a valid 4D user or the developer of the 4D application has to have written code in the `On SQL Authentication` database method (of the 4D application) to handle the login in a custom way.

More info regarding [managing 4D Users](http://doc.4d.com/4Dv15/4D/15.1/Managing-users-and-groups.300-2679370.en.html)

More info regarding the [`On SQL Authentication` database method](http://doc.4d.com/4Dv15/4D/15/On-SQL-Authentication-Database-Method.300-2007433.en.html)